# Related to Errors in Terminal in Ubuntu 23.04 in my VirtualBox

Tags: gedit

```
** (gedit 2896): WARNING **; 20:08:20.343: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit 2896): WARNING **; 20:08:20.344: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-bookmarks not supported

** (gedit 2896): WARNING **; 20:08:20.345: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit 2896): WARNING **; 20:08:20.513: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata :: gedit-position not supported
```

Comment: "Your VirtualBox" is missing some `gedit` plugins that you configured it to use.

Comment: Then how to configure it? Can anyone suggest?